Generators for the image of a projection of a polynomial space onto an eigenspace of an involution
Note: I have almost completely rewritten the post in order to make it more specific.
I have the following setup. Let $[n] := \{1, \dots, n \}$ and let $C_2([n]) = \{ (i, j) \in [n] \times [n] | \, i \neq j \}$. Let $R$, resp. $C$, denote the group of row-preserving, resp. column-preserving permutations of $C_2([n])$ (in other words, these are permutations of $C_2([n])$ which fix the first, resp. second, index).
Let $A = \mathbb{Q}[(u_{ij}, v_{ij}) | \, (i, j) \in C_2([n]]$.
Let $\sigma$ be the permutation of $C_2([n])$ which interchanges the two indices, i.e. it maps $(i, j)$ to $(j, i)$.
We note that if $g_1 \in R$, then $\sigma g_1 \sigma^{-1} \in C$ and if $g_2 \in C$, then $\sigma g_2 \sigma^{-1} \in R$. Actually, conjugation by $\sigma$ is a group isomorphism from $R$ to $C$, and also from $C$ to $R$.
Let $f \in A$ be defined by
$$ f((u_{ij}, v_{ij}) = \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} (u_{ij} v_{ji} - v_{ij} u_{ji}). $$
Note that both $R$ and $C$ naturally act on $F$. We are interested in the sum
$$ S = \sum_{g_1 \in R} g_1 . f + \sum_{g_2 \in C} g_2 . f. $$
Note that
$$ \sigma . S = (-1)^{\binom{n}{2}} S.$$
We can also rewrite $S$ as
$$ \begin{align} S &= \sum_{g_1 \in R} (g_1 + \sigma g_1 \sigma^{-1}).f \\
&= \sum_{g_1 \in R} (g_1 + (-1)^{\binom{n}{2}} \sigma g_1).f \\
&= 2 \sum_{g_1 \in R}\left(\frac{\mathbf{1} + (-1)^{\binom{n}{2}} \sigma}{2}\right)(g_1.f),\end{align}$$
where the second equality was obtained using $\sigma.f = (-1)^{\binom{n}{2}} f$. We can now more directly see that $\sigma.S = (-1)^{\binom{n}{2}} S$.
Let
$$ \pi = \frac{\mathbf{1} + (-1)^{\binom{n}{2}} \sigma}{2}.$$
It is a projection operator onto the $\lambda = (-1)^{\binom{n}{2}}$ eigenspace of $\sigma$. We have thus proved that
$$ S = 2 \sum_{g_1 \in R} \pi(g_1.f). $$
I conjecture that $S$ can be rewritten as a linear combination
$$ S = \sum_{g \in R^\sigma(f)} c_g g.f,$$
for some $c_g \in \mathbb{Q}$, for $g \in R^\sigma(f)$, where $R^\sigma(f)$ consists of all $g \in R$ such that $\pi(g.f) = g.f$.
Remark: Let $B$ be the linear span of $\{ g_1.f ; \, g_1 \in R \}$. If $\pi(B)$ happened to be spanned by the $\{ g.f ; g \in R^\sigma(f) \}$, then the conjecture would follow.
